# Unable to load resource from classpath in Heroku Java app

Tags: java, maven, heroku, classpath

I am having trouble accessing a resource file at runtime, which is stored in the resources folder of my JAVA project.

The project is Spring Boot based and I have stored some ddl and json configuration files under src/main/resources. 
The project gets deployed correctly (through Maven). However, when my code tries to access one of those resource files I get the following exception:

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/app/target/app-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/setup_data/app_data_schema.ddl

I can see from the logs that just before this exception another file gets loaded correclty by Spring from the same location 
(file:/app/target/app-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/setup_data/schema.sql).

I have also double checked using the heroku CLI ("heroku run bash") that indeed the files have been deployed to the location I am expecting:
/app/target/classes/setup_data
- test_app_data1.json
- test_app_data2.json
- app_data_schema.ddl

This leads me to believe that the problem is in the way I am loading the files, which works locally on my machine but not when deployed to Heroku. 
This is the code I am using to figure out the full path of the file:

```
public static String getFullPathForResource(Class<?> resourceClass, String resourceName) {
    URL resourceUrl = resourceClass.getResource(resourceName);
    String fullPath = "";
    if (resourceUrl != null) {
        fullPath = resourceUrl.getPath();
    }

    return fullPath;
}
```

I then load the file as follows:

```
String ddlResourceFullPath = getFullPathForResource(getClass(), ddlResource);
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(ddlResourceFullPath));
```

The result of the getFullPathForResource() method is indeed:
"file:/app/target/app-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/schema.sql"

Which from my understanding should match the correct path of my resource!

Could you guide me on to how to correclty load the resource file?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pointed to the issue by Heroku's support.

The issue lied in the way I was loading the file, not how I was finding the path to the resource.
Specifically, this line:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(ddlResourceFullPath));
```

Files.lines expects the file to be on the file system and is not going to be able to open a file inside the Jar file.

Using `java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` resolves the issue. (eg: `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream()` )